# Azure eventhub load distribution

Tags: performance, azure, azure-eventhub

I have an eventhub solution where there are alot of publishers publishing data to the hub. Currently we are not using partitions. I would like to have a solution where there can be multiple listeners/subscribers who can listen to these events in parallel. E.g
If there is an eventA and an eventB, can I have only one listener recieve the eventA and other listener receive the eventB so that the load can be distributed?
I have to do some compute on each event so I want the computed distributed and not duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what partitions are for. For a given consumer group, there can be multiple readers splitting their work among them, but their max amount is limited by partition count.

Each consumer would lock 1 or more partitions, and will be the only one working on events from those.

Comment: You should also look at Epoch to account for competing consumers -  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gyan/2014/09/02/event-hubs-receiver-epoch/